# Move a varbinary from one table to another with a check in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, varbinary

I need to copy a specific `varbinary` column from one table to another if it answer a simple if check.

First varbinary is from `[OLDROWGAME].[dbo].[TblUnifiedItemStore1]` database in a table called `Store` where UID=1, need to be moved to `[ROWgame].[dbo].[TblUnifiedItemStore1]` to a table named `Store` WHERE UID=1

Any way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are those two databases on the same server? Or are those two servers on the same network, e.g. can you connect to both servers from a single Management Studio instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 declare @1 table(a int , b varbinary)
 insert into @1 values(1,101010)

 declare @2 table(a int , b varbinary)
 insert into @2(a) values(1)

 update @2
 set b=(select b from @1 where a=1)
 where a=1

  select * from @2
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your table in object explorer and press "edit top 200 rows". Then you select the row(s) you want to move and press copy or cut. Then you go to your new table and again press "edit top 200 rows" and then press paste.